# sending content-encoding header in django

Tags: django, httpresponse, content-encoding, render-to-response

Hello I want to have a plaintext version of my content available. So I have a separate template for that. I am calling `render_to_response` with `mimetype="text/plain"` but i want to tell a browser opening that page in the http-response that the content is utf-8 encoded. How do i do that (e.g. what do i have to add to `render_to_response`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add charset to mimetype like this:

```
mimetype="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

---

What really happens behind scene is that mimetype is taken out of kwargs in `render_to_response`.

```
httpresponse_kwargs = {'mimetype': kwargs.pop('mimetype', None)}
return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
```

and sent to `HttpResponse` which sets it as `content_type`:

```
if mimetype:
    content_type = mimetype     # For backwards compatibility
if not content_type:
    content_type = "%s; charset=%s" % (settings.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE,
                settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
```

Comment: In new versions of Django the parameter is called content_type insted of mimetype.